# Compute $\int_0^\pi\frac{\cos nx}{a^2-2ab\cos x+b^2}\, dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

> How to compute the following integral
>   \begin{equation}
> \int_0^\pi\frac{\cos nx}{a^2-2ab\cos x+b^2}\, dx
> \end{equation}

I have been given two integral questions by my teacher. I cannot answer this one. I have also searched the similar question here but it looks like nothing is similar so I think this is not a duplicate. I could compute the integral if 
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\pi\frac{dx}{a^2-2ab\cos x+b^2}
\end{equation}
The $\cos nx$ part makes the integral is really difficult. I want to use the result to compute this integral (the real question given by my teacher)
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\pi\frac{x^2\cos nx}{a^2-2ab\cos x+b^2}\, dx
\end{equation}
My question is how to compute the first integral (in the grey-shaded part) preferably with **elementary ways (high school methods)**?

Comment: Is $n$ an integer?

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt I think $n$ is not necessarily integer

Comment: For $n=0$, use the [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution) to show that $I_0=\dfrac\pi{a^2-b^2}$ . Then try establishing the recurrence relation $I_n=\dfrac ba\cdot I_{n-1}$ , perhaps by using some basic or elementary angle addition formulas for the cosine function.

Comment: Unfortunately, the formula for integers does not apply to fractional cases, so differentiating it is not possible, since it is discontinuous, and a more general formula would imply special functions. Indeed, even for small values of *n*, the integral your teacher gave you requires polylogarithms.

Comment: @Lucian I tried but failed. I've asked my friend, $n$ only for integer. The answer is $\left(\cfrac{a}{b}\right)^n\cfrac{\pi}{b^2-a^2}$

Comment: @V-Moy: If $b>a>0$, then it is as you say. If $a>b>0$, it is as I wrote.

Comment: @Lucian I know, it doesn't matter at all. The problem is how to get that value using an elementary way

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Let $I_n(a,b)$ be the desired integral. Note that $I_n(a,b)=I_n(b,a)$, and $I_n(a,b)=I_n(-a,-b)$. So, we may suppose that $|b|< a$ Note that
$$\eqalign{
\frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2-2ab\cos x+b^2}&=\frac{a}{a-e^{ix}b}+\frac{be^{-ix}}{a-e^{-ix}b}\cr
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^ne^{inx}+\frac{be^{-ix}}{a}\sum_{n=0}^\infty
\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^ne^{-inx}\cr
&=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^ne^{inx}+ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{n}e^{-inx}\cr
&=1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^n\cos(n x)
}
$$
It follows, using the uniform convergence of the series on $[0,\pi]$, that
$$
\int_0^\pi\frac{(a^2-b^2)\cos(mx)}{a^2-2ab\cos x+b^2}dx
=\int_0^\pi\cos(mx)dx+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^n\int_0^\pi\cos(n x)\cos(mx)dx
$$
But $\int_0^\pi\cos(n x)\cos(mx)dx=0$ if $n\ne m$, and 
$\int_0^\pi\cos^2(n x)dx=\pi/2$ if $n\ne0$. So
$$\eqalign{I_m(a,b)=
\int_0^\pi\frac{\cos(mx)}{a^2-2ab\cos x+b^2}dx
&=\left\{\matrix{\frac{\pi}{a^2-b^2}&\hbox{if}&m=0\cr
\frac{\pi}{a^2-b^2}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^m&\hbox{if}&m\ne0
}
\right.}
$$
which is the desired formula for $|b|<a$.

Comment: Very clever answer Professor, +1. You use Taylor series for $\displaystyle\frac{1}{1-y}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty y^n$ and it holds for $|y|<1$, does it also hold if $y$ is a complex number? What does this notation actually mean $|...|$? Absolute value for $y$ is a negative number or absolute value for $y$ is a complex number? Perhaps both?

Comment: I think the case for $m\neq0$, the answer should be $\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{a^2-b^2}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^m$.

Comment: @V-Moy: BTW, did you teacher presented you a solution to this problem?

Comment: @V-Moy, the proposed solution works in fact if the absolute value of $b$ as a complex number is smaller than the absolute value of $a$ also as a complex number.

Comment: (+1) This is known as the Poisson Kernel http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel

Comment: So the series also works for complex number. Okay then, thank you so much Prof Kouba, I learnt a lot from your answer. Thanks a bunch. (ô‿ô)

Comment: @PranavArora No. My teacher never gives the class any solutions of the assignment or test. Assignment will always be assignment (even forever!) unless one of us can give the solution and he/she who correctly answers it will get extra points. The reason why my teacher never gives us the solution is to make our class always competitive.

Comment: @GrahamHesketh Thanks for the link that you gave Sir. I really like it. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: @V-Moy: Ah ok, are you allowed to consult your classmates? If so, did any of them solve it? :)

Comment: Of course but they often keep it for their selves except when they prove it their work to our teacher. It's hard to make friends in this course because almost all of them individualistic.

Answer (score 11):

Assume for definiteness that $a>b>0$.

**Method 1**:

For integer $n\geq0$, we can rewrite the integral as
$$\frac{1}{4ab}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{e^{in x}dx}{\cosh\gamma-\cos x}=\frac{1}{2ia^2}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{z^{n}dz}{(z-e^{-\gamma})(1-e^{-\gamma}z)},$$
where $e^{\gamma}=\frac{a}{b}$. Computing the residue at $z=e^{-\gamma}$, we find for the last integral
$$2\pi i \cdot \frac{1}{2ia^2}\cdot\frac{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^n}{1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}}=\frac{\pi}{a^2-b^2}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^n.$$

**Method 2**:

Similarly  rewrite the integral as
$$\frac{1}{2(a^2-b^2)}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{b}{a}e^{ix}}+\frac{\frac{b}{a}e^{-ix}}{1-\frac{b}{a}e^{-ix}}\right)e^{in x}dx.$$
Then expand the integrand into series in $\frac{b}{a}$ and use that $\displaystyle\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{inx}dx=2\pi\cdot\delta_{n,0}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sir but I'm not familiar with this method. I also know that $a^2-2ab\cos x+b^2=(a-be^{ix})(a-be^{-ix})$. +1 for your effort. (ô‿ô)

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a proof yet, but with some computer assistance, this is what I believe to be the answer when $n$ is a non-negative integer.

\begin{align*}
  \int_0^\pi\frac{\cos nx}{a^2-2ab\cos x+b^2}\, dx &= \frac{\displaystyle \left(\left(a^{2n}+b^{2n}\right)\, \left(\Big\lvert \frac{a+b}{a-b}\Big\rvert +1\right)-2\, \sum_{k=0}^{2n}a^k\, b^{2n-k}\right)\, \pi}{\displaystyle 2\, a^n\, b^n\, (a+b)^2}
\end{align*}

I think there might be a reduction formula for this, but at the moment I don't know.

Comment: For integer $n$ the result is (very) easy to get by residues.

Comment: $\bigg(\dfrac ba\bigg)^n\dfrac\pi{a^2-b^2}~$ looks much nicer.

Comment: Mr. @O.L. Please share your thought. I'd love to see it $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Mr. @Lucian also. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for your suggestions and the simplified form! I'm not adept with complex analysis yet. I too would like to see your answers.

Comment: @V-Moy : Thank you! It looks really difficult to get the answer by elementary methods.

Answer (score 1):

See the last comment in

[Evaluating $\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\cos n\eta\,d\eta}{1+a^2+2a\cos m\eta}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3659885/evaluating-int-0-pi-frac-cos-n-eta-d-eta1a22a-cos-m-eta/3662334#3662334)

for the answer to your original `$x^2\cos nx$' integral which I don't think is answered in any of the above posts.