# Need help evaluating the integral $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \dfrac{x \sin x\ dx}{1- 2a \cos x + a^2}$ where $0 < a < 1$.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Need help evaluating the complex integral $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \dfrac{x \sin x\ dx}{1- 2a \cos x + a^2}$ where $0 < a < 1$.

Comment: I have tried this: \begin{align*}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \dfrac{x \sin x\ dx}{1- 2a \cos x + a^2} &= \Im \left [ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \dfrac{x e^{ix}\ dx}{(a - e^{ix})(a - e^{-ix})} \right ] \\
&=   \Im \left [ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \dfrac{-i log(z) z\ dx}{(a - z)(a - z^{-1})} \frac{dz}{iz} \right ] \\
&=   \Im \left [ \int_{C_1} \dfrac{- log(z) z\ dx}{(a-z)(az-1)}\ dz \right ] \\
&=   \Im \left [ \int_{C_1} \dfrac{- log(z) z\ dx}{(a-z)(az-1)}\ dz \right ] \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Almost surely a duplicate....

Comment: Here goes. Your answer is exactly twice of this integral http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822484/a-difficult-integral-evaluation-problem