# Evaluating by real methods $\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x^5}{2-\cos^2(x)}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

$\def\Li{{\rm{Li}}}$I'm sure you guys can briefly get the result by some methods of complex analysis, but now
I'm only interested in **real analysis methods** of proving the result. What would you propose
for that?
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x^5}{2-\cos^2(x)}\ dx=&\,\frac{\pi^6 \sqrt{2}}{768}+\frac{5 \sqrt{2}\pi^4}{64}\Li_2\left(2\sqrt2-3\right)-\frac{15\sqrt{2}\pi^2}{16}\Li_4\left(2\sqrt2-3\right)\\
&+\,\frac{15\sqrt{2}}{8}\bigg[\Li_6\left(2\sqrt2-3\right)-\Li_6\left(3-2\sqrt2\right)\bigg]
\end{align*}

And a *supplementary question*  for another version, that is

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x^5}{1+\cos^2(x)}\ dx$$
again, by **real analysis methods** only.

Comment: Guess what ? The antiderivatives can be found and from there the results !!

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I see. My feeling is that there should be some very easy ways of computing both integrals by methods of real analysis.

Comment: I enjoy your humor ! You make my day. Seriously, I don't have any idea about these monsters could be computed by methods of real analysis. Cheers :-)

Comment: the result contains the PolyLog function.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Glad to read that. However, I strongly believe such methods should exist, and I suppose they are incredibly fast and easy. Cheers :-)

Comment: I hope so but don't rely on me for anything in this area ! If I amy ask you : how did come this fascination for integrals ? Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Oh, I was fascinated by the marvellous connections between integrals, series and limits, the way one can combine them to get amazing solutions. In short, I love the world of math connections.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Me too. I don't like handcuffed methods.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using double angle formula, the integrand can be rewritten as
\begin{equation}
I=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x^5}{2-\cos^2(x)}\ dx=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{2x^5}{3-\cos(2x)}\ dx
\end{equation}
Mapping the variable $2x\mapsto x$, we have
\begin{equation}
I=\frac{1}{32}\int_0^{\pi} \frac{x^5}{3-\cos x}\ dx
\end{equation}
Using identity (proof can be seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/816253/133248))
\begin{equation}
1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^n\cos(n x)=\frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2+b^2-2ab\cos x}\qquad,\qquad\mbox{for}\, |b|<a
\end{equation}
and the correspondence values $a=\dfrac{2+\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and $b=\dfrac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2}$, one may find
\begin{equation}
1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)^n\cos(n x)=\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3-\cos x}
\end{equation}
Therefore
\begin{align}
I&=\frac{1}{64\sqrt{2}}\int_0^{\pi} \left[x^5+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)^n x^5\cos(n x)\right]\ dx\\
&=\frac{1}{64\sqrt{2}} \left[\frac{\pi^6}{6}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)^n \int_0^{\pi} x^5 \cos(n x)\ dx\right]\\
\end{align}
The rest part can be done by multiple times integration by parts and using $\sin(n\pi)=0$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. We will obtain
\begin{equation}
I=\frac{\pi^6 \sqrt{2}}{768}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{64}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)^n \left[\frac{5\pi^4\cos(\pi n)}{n^2}-\frac{60\pi^2\cos(\pi n)}{n^4}+\frac{120\cos(\pi n)}{n^6}-\frac{120}{n^6}\right]\
\end{equation}
Using
\begin{equation}
\cos(n\pi)=\begin{cases}\,\,+1&,\,\,\mbox{if}\,\, n\,\,\mbox{is even}\\[12pt]
\,\,-1&,\,\,\mbox{if}\,\, n\,\,\mbox{is odd}\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
and the representation of polylogarithm function in term of its infinite series, we finally obtain
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{x^5}{2-\cos^2(x)}\ dx=&\,\frac{\pi^6 \sqrt{2}}{768}+\frac{5 \sqrt{2}\pi^4}{64}\text{Li}_2\left(2\sqrt2-3\right)-\frac{15\sqrt{2}\pi^2}{16}\text{Li}_4\left(2\sqrt2-3\right)\\
&+\,\frac{15\sqrt{2}}{8}\bigg[\text{Li}_6\left(2\sqrt2-3\right)-\text{Li}_6\left(3-2\sqrt2\right)\bigg]
\end{align*}
The same approach can be applied for evaluating the second integral.

Comment: Good job! (+1) I think we don't need the tools you mentioned at the end.

Comment: Bravo! You have there a complete answer. I chose your answer. (anyway, I didn't have other option) ;)

Comment: That was sweet !! :D