# Integrate $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\tan x}{1+m^2\tan^2 x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, logarithms

> Integrate $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\tan x}{1+m^2\tan^2 x}dx$

$\newcommand{\intd}[1]{\,\mathrm{d}#1}$
**My Attempt**

Put $t=\tan x\implies\intd t=\sec^2x\intd x$
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\tan x}{1+m^2\tan^2 x}dx&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\tan x\cdot\sec^2x}{(1+m^2\tan^2 x)\sec^2x}\intd x\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t}{(1+m^2t^2)(1+t^2)}\intd t
\end{align*}
Put $t^2=y\implies 2t\intd t=\intd y$
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{dy}{(1+m^2y)(1+y)}&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\bigg[\frac{1}{1-m^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1+y}+\frac{m^2}{m^2-1}\cdot\frac{1}{1+m^2y}\bigg]dy\\
&=\frac{1}{2(1-m^2)}\int_0^\infty\frac{dy}{1+y}-\frac{m^2}{2(1-m^2)}\int_0^\infty\frac{dy}{1+m^2y}\\
&=\bigg[\frac{1}{2(1-m^2)}\log|1+y|-\frac{1}{2(1-m^2)}\log|1+m^2y|\bigg]_0^\infty\\
&=\bigg[\frac{1}{2(1-m^2)}\log|\frac{1+y}{1+m^2y}|\bigg]_0^\infty=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2(1-m^2)}\bigg[\frac{\infty}{\infty}-0\bigg]}\end{align*}
I think I am getting stuck here as the substitutions does not seem to give the solution ?

**Doubt**
$$
\lim_{y\to 0}\log|\frac{1+y}{1+m^2y}|=\log 1=0\\
\lim_{y\to \infty}\log|\frac{1+y}{1+m^2y}|=\lim_{y\to \infty}\log|\frac{\frac{1}{y}+1}{\frac{1}{y}+m^2}|=\log\frac{1}{m^2}
$$
So what really we are doing with definite integrals ?. Does this mean that we are actually computing the upper and lower limits and taking the difference to find the definite integral ?

**Note:** Expanding in terms of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ gives the solution, no doubt about limit going to infinity, not looking for that.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1005976/finding-int-0-pi-2-frac-tan-x1m2-tan2x-mathrmdx/1006068#1006068

Comment: @tired how do u find example qstn. I searched, nothing showed up. btw i have edited OP, hope it makes my doubt clear.

Comment: i rembered that i answered something similar many years ago :)

Answer (score 2):

You have one error $$\frac{m^2}{1-m^2}\int\frac{1}{1+m^2y}\,\mathrm{d}y=\frac{1}{1-m^2}\log|1+m^2y|+C$$
So your final answer is 
\begin{align*}
\bigg[\frac{1}{2(1-m^2)}\log|1+y|-\frac{1}{2(1-m^2)}\log|1+m^2y|\bigg]_0^\infty&=\frac{1}{2(1-m^2)}\left[\log|1+y|-\log|1+m^2y|\right]_0^\infty\\
&=\frac{1}{2(1-m^2)}\log\left|\frac{1+y}{1+m^2y}\right|\bigg\rvert_0^\infty\\
&=\frac{1}{2(1-m^2)}\log\left(\frac1{m^2}\right)\\
&=\boxed{\frac{\log m}{m^2-1}}
\end{align*}

Comment: thnx. it was by mistake.. my actual doubt was regarding the $\frac{\infty}{\infty}-0$ form in the solution

Answer (score 1):

I think that you could have done it faster avoiding the second change of variable since, as you wrote, 
$$
I=\int\frac{\tan (x)}{1+m^2\tan^2 (x)}\,dx=\int\frac{t}{(1+m^2t^2)(1+t^2)}\,dt
$$ Now, partial fraction decomposition gives 
$$\frac{t}{(1+m^2t^2)(1+t^2)}=\frac{m^2 t}{\left(m^2-1\right) \left(1+m^2 t^2\right)}-\frac{t}{\left(m^2-1\right)
   \left(1+t^2\right)}$$ making 
$$I=\int\frac{t}{(1+m^2t^2)(1+t^2)}\,dt=\frac{\log \left(1+m^2 t^2\right)-\log \left(1+t^2\right)}{2(m^2-1)}$$ $$I=\frac 1{2(m^2-1)}\log\left(\frac{1+m^2t^2}{1+t^2}\right)$$

Comment: thnx. but pls check i have edited OP, hope it now makes my doubt clear.

Comment: @ss1729. I deleted a stupid comment from mine. When $t\to \infty$, $\frac{1+m^2t^2}{1+t^2}\to m^2$